# How to transfer wordpress mysql md5 user passwords field into another mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a WP website and another website with similar service. I want to duplicate db user password and email fields into new mysql database.

`$A$B6NS8Cv837YVS1c/JKLE1` - WP password (example)
`83703ccdb3cb2dad97f76f986400b43f87b989ce` - Another website MD5 password (example)

And the question is how I can transfer WP user's passwords to a new mysql table so they can work?

Thanks

Comment: Check WP code to see how exactly they hash it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not use the same encryption scheme, or some kind of SSO?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can't - it's rather the point of hashing passwords that you can't undo it. You could potentially use a rainbow table to try and crack the MD5 hashes and get the original password before re-hashing it the way Wordpress does it, but if your users' passwords are vulnerable to such an attack, you should probably be concerned for their account security!

Personally, I would announce to the users that a big merge is happening, and for safety reasons they must change their password. A lot of people will probably just "change" it to the same thing, and that's fine, because internally you're just rehashing the password and can then delete the old, unsafe MD5 hash.

Comment: As far as I see, this is simply false. There is no problem in reusing the same password algorithm that Wordpress uses

Answer (score 1):

You will copy the md5 password into your new system.

Then you can have a login screen which does the exact same hashing on the entered password and compares the two.

Encryption is one way so you will never know the password but you certainly will be able to use it in another system.

As someone mentioned in the comments you will need to know exactly how WordPress hashes the password but this should all be in the source code.

However if you have other users already in the system that use a different hashing system you will need to flag them to decide what hashing to do.

When they do decide to change their password or via recommendation, you can migrate them to the other hashing system.